# Mule SugarCRM Connector: Schema Not Found

Tags: mule, esb, sugarcrm, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I have a SugarCRM Connector on an Anypoint Studio instance but the schema isn't found.

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sugar

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sugar/current/mule-sugar.xsd

Details: http://mulesoft.github.io/sugarcrm-connector/1.0.3/apidocs/mule/sugar-config.html

Because of this, I do not get to use this on a Mule Domain Project.

When I deploy, the following message is displayed on the ESB Server:

> WARN  2016-02-08 12:45:01,526 [main]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Ignored
>   XML validation warning org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document
>   'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sugar/current/mule-sugar.xsd',
>   because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
>   read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

Is the link unavailable? Is this a problem or iss there another link schema?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The schema for SugarCRM Connector (or for any Mule connector), isn't publicly available, it is located **inside** the connector JAR, which should be installed in your **`CLASSPATH`**.

[image]

**Option 1:** Drag & drop a SugarCRM component from the Studio palette into the canvas.

**Option 2:** Right-click on your Mule project > Properties > Libraries > Add Library... > Anypoint Connector Dependencies > Choose the SugarCRM connector.